# How to use the find command to list the path names of files including spaces?

Tags: command-line

```
find ~ -iname "*.mp3"
```

I want to find all .mp3 files in my home directory and onwards.

Here are some of the results:

> /home/koshy/Music/These Boots Are Made for Walkin   Nancy Sinatra.mp3
>   /home/koshy/Music/alicia keys - Killing me softly (live at Showcase).mp3

Notice how the spaces in them are not escaped?

Once I have the files, I want to copy one or two of them to a new location. But then I was forced to manually change file name, which can be exceedingly tedious:

```
cp /home/koshy/Music/alicia\ keys\ -\ Killing\ me\ softly\ (live\ at\ Showcase).mp3 .
```

(Note how the spaces are now escaped)?

Surely there is a better way?

Comment: *cp 'some file name.mp3' .* or *cp "file $name.mp3" .* (remember to escape metacharacter and control operator too)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one:

```
$ find Downloads/ -iname "* *" -print0 | xargs -0 ls 
'Downloads/Cloud/Multi-Runtime Microservices Architecture.pdf'

$ cp 'Downloads/Cloud/Multi-Runtime Microservices Architecture.pdf' .
```

[More ways to do it](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/81349/how-do-i-use-find-when-the-filename-contains-spaces).